# Enumeration value 'UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown' not handled in switch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

```
  switch(_outputImageOrientation)
            {
                case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:outputRotation = kGPUImageRotateRightFlipVertical; break;
                case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:outputRotation = kGPUImageRotate180; break;
                case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:outputRotation = kGPUImageFlipHorizonal; break;
                case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:outputRotation = kGPUImageFlipVertical; break;
```

This is my code and I am getting following error:
Enumeration value 'UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown' not handled in switch

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you added a default block in switch or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add the `default:break;` statement in your switch.

Answer (score 6):

There are 5 values defined in the `UIInterfaceOrientation` enum.

In your switch, you don't check the `UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown`.

If you don't want to check it, just add a `default:break;` statement, else add a `UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown:..` statement.

Answer (score 1):

According to this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/frameworks/UIKit.html

UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown was added to ios 8.0.